# Need help with a trigger to update custom field based on new ContentNote

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, contentversion, contentnote

I am having an issue getting this trigger to fire. The requirements are that when a new ContentNote is created on the Opportunity record, I need Opportunity.Last_Note__c to update with the Title of the Note.

I have tried to use flow builder and that wasn't successful. Through the community, it seems that a trigger is a better option. Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding.

This is the trigger I've been trying:

```
    trigger UpdateLastNoteOpp on ContentDocumentLink (after insert) {
    List<Opportunity> oppUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
    for(ContentDocumentLink cn : Trigger.new){
        if(cn.LinkedEntityId != null && cn.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType() == Opportunity.sObjectType){
            Opportunity opp=new Opportunity(Id=cn.LinkedEntityId,Last_Note__c=n.Title);
            oppUpdate.add(opp);

       } 
    }
    
    if(oppUpdate.size()>0){
        update oppUpdate;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I haven't worked with ContentVersion, ContentNote or Note objects specifically, so I don't know if Salesforce is weird in this area. But typically, you'll want the "on [ObjectType] (after insert)" section to match the object type of Trigger.new. It looks like "Note" is used in one place, and "ContentVersion" in another. If you were able to save it, then this may be a supported, weird Saleforce thing. But if you weren't able to save the trigger, and received a compilation error, then that might be something to try changing up.

Comment: @NathanaelSchmolze is correct. Note and ContentNote are completely different objects with different schemas.

Comment: It's a note on notes and attachments component. I know when I create a flow, I use ContentDocument for the note data. I read on the dev site that I would need to trigger from ContentVersion for this, but I'm not sure how to construct it. 

Any suggestion on how I can accomplish what I need?

Comment: You need to write your trigger on `ContentDocumentLink` since that is what joins the note to its related object (Opportunity), see [ContentNote Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm) diagram.

Comment: @DavidCheng You are correct, thank you! Editing my post with the updated code. I'm an Administrator (aspiring Developer), but I am very green with writing apex. Can you take a look and help me link in ConentNote? The objective is to update Opportunity.Last_Note__c with the related ContentNote Title.

Comment: you're going to need a strategy to decide what to do when the trigger has 2+ ContentDocumentLinks to the same Opportunity -- which ContentNote title do you assign to the Opportunity LAst_note__c field?

Comment: @cropredy I want to trigger the update every time a new note is created. Can I make it only fire then?

Comment: Triggers can run in bulk.  My point was that if there was a dataload of many content notes all referencing the same Oppo- which one stamps the Oppo. The decision might be simply - it doesn't matter